# mdx query for showing YTD value of the whole set and the subset in the same table

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

I have customer dimension that contains business unit, customer name,.. and fact table with transactions made by each customer (with date of the transaction)

I need to show (in the same table) YTD number of transactions for all customers per business unit and, in another column, YTD number of transaction for all customers whose number of transactions has fallen by 40% in the last 3 months

I managed to get the list of customers whose transaction volume has fallen, but somehow I don't have an idea how to show in the same table (query) the YTD tran. volume of all customers per business unit and YTD volume of these specific customers per business unit

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? Or just post your mdx expression for the customers whose transactions have falledn by 40%. It sounds like you might want a calculated measure in your query to get the YTD number for that subset of customers.